# Split Record into multiple column after Row_number and Partition By

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to have my result to be displayed in 4 columns.
This is how I did my coding.

```
SELECT T.MT_CARD_TYP_ID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.APP_ID ORDER BY T.DT_CREATE) AS RN
FROM T_CS_FAC_CC T 
WHERE app_id = '8F9A97B0CB5349429C44F15830EDC18F';
```

What should I do the next step? Can someone pro help me out please?

This is how my result look

[image: This is how my result look.]

This is how I want the result look like.

[image: This is how I want the result look like.]

Comment: You are looking for `pivot`

Comment: Where should I add the pivot into my query above using row_number?

Comment: condition aggravated function

Comment: Could you please give me an example? I'm not really understand

Comment: How could you create the `app_id` column?

Comment: the app_id exists in t_cs_fac_cc and it is refer to app table ID. Btw, I found this worked. Just want to import it back to my SP query but it says too many values. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: I wrote an answer is that work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use condition aggravated function.

```
SELECT app_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN MT_CARD_TYP_ID END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN MT_CARD_TYP_ID END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN MT_CARD_TYP_ID END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 4 THEN MT_CARD_TYP_ID END)
FROM (
    SELECT T.MT_CARD_TYP_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.APP_ID ORDER BY T.DT_CREATE) AS RN 
    FROM T_CS_FAC_CC T 
    where app_id='8F9A97B0CB5349429C44F15830EDC18F'
)t1
GROUP BY app_id
```